# How to Import Data from S3 Bucket into MySQL Database using JDBC or ODBC Connectivity

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to import Data from AWS S3 Bucket into MySQL Database using JDBC or ODBC Connectivity. I want to know how it's done? I tried using AWS Lambda but I need to do it only using JDBC or ODBC connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an AWS Lambda function and using the Java Lambda runtime. Use the AWS S3 Java API to read the data from an Amazon S3 bucket from within the Lambda function. Also use the Java JDBC API to insert the data into the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

1. pyodbc is a popular odbc module if you are interested in using python.
2. mysql connectors are popular (also in python)
3. AUrora mysql also supports rds-data api. This means you can simply use boto3 to batch load your data into mysql....